# Adding floor to house model

Tags: archilogic

I am trying to add a polyfloor to a house model I created in Blender. When I drag and drop the polyfloor to the house model, the size of the floor is so small that I cannot even select the corners to increase the size. Could someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: thx for asking! does the answer by @madlaina-kalunder answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @tomas, I just marked that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archilogic models are using the metric system, that means 1 unit = 1 meter.

Your model in Blender most likely is not scaled properly to match real world sizes, therefore your house is too large. Try to downscale your model.

Please include your model or some code to update your question, if this does not help you.

Comment: Thank you @madlaina, exactly the answer I was looking for